# Formal construction of the maximum planar graph of order n.

Tags: graph-theory

does someone knows a method to do it?
My intuition says it will include creating an n-1-gon with a middle vertex, then connect all the n-1 vertices to the center and then for each vertex vi connect it to vi-1 and vi+1. But where I get stuck is how to formally triangulize the outer face, it maybe has something to do with modulo?

Answer (score 4):

First of all maximal planar graphs are not unique, as the following two nonisomorphic graphs (consider degrees) demonstrate:

[image: nonisomorphic maximal planar graphs of order 6]

If you want to show that there exists a maximal planar graph of any given order $n$ you can use induction and iteratively add a new vertex to the outer face and connect it to all vertices on the outer face, as indicated by the following picture.

[image: sequence of triangulated graphs]

To prove that any planar graph can be triangulated (i.e. is subgraph of a maximal planar graph of the same order) can be done by induction as well, but is slightly more involved.