# Proving by induction the construction of a planar graph with maximum number of edges.

Tags: graph-theory, induction, planar-graphs

I'm trying to prove a construction by induction that for a planar graph, the maximum number of edges is $3v-6<=e$.

The construction suggested to me from this diagram:
[image: sequence of triangulated graphs]

from here: [Formal construction of the maximum planar graph of order n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645506/formal-construction-of-the-maximum-planar-graph-of-order-n/3645605#3645605)

basis $v=3$: $3*3-6<=3$. check.
step: here I have some troubles, I get some things mixed is that what I should prove: $3(k+1)-6<=m$?

Comment: I don't see why it is a duplicate... Its a new approach to prove, and this time its only speaks about lower bound even that its the same.

Comment: Because I thought its the easiest way to prove the lower bound... And I'm proving a certain construction here.

Comment: Its a lower bound on the maximum number of edges.

Comment: Wait, is actually showing the construction may be ebough proof for the lower bound?

Comment: Formalizing the construction (*which will include some sort of inductive or recursive argument in terms of how to actually draw what you describe*) and explaining why it has as many vertices and edges as you say and is planar...

Comment: the first 3 vertices are a triangle. From the 4th vertex on for each vertex i I connect an edge between vertex i and vertex i-1, and also vertex i to the first two vertices (the basis of the triangle if you want to call them that way)

Comment: And?  so... at each step, we have increased the number of vertices by one and the number of edges by three.  It is clear that if we had an $n$ vertex graph which had $e$ edges that was made from this construction that moving from one step in the construction to the next increased the number of vertices by one and the number of edges by three.  By induction hypothesis, for the $n$ vertex graph we had $3n-6$ vertices, so for the $n+1$ vertex graph as we increased the number of edges by three we have $(3n-6)+3$ vertices which we see by algebra is equal to $3(n+1)-6$

Comment: The construction shows one way to construct a maximal planar graph of order $n$, but it's not necessarily the only (up to isomorphism) maximal planar graph of order $n$. Hence you can't use the construction to prove something about all maximal planar graphs of order $n$.

Comment: Yes I know that. My only intention was to prove by induction the lower bound using this construction.

Comment: Then see JMoravitz's latest comment.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you attempting to prove that there is a planar graph for any $v\ge 3$ with the maximal number of edges, $e=3v-6$.

Your base case is correct: we can just exhibit the triangle graph and check that it meets the desired formula.

For the inductive step, we need to go from our *inductive hypothesis* that there is a graph $G$ for $v\ge 3$ such that  $e=3v-6$, and prove that we can construct a graph $G'$ on $v{+}1$ vertices with $e=3(v+1)-6 = 3v-3$.

The figure suggests the method here. If we examine the planar graph $G(V,E)$ we see that the face (region) outside the graph is bounded by $3$ edges. To make $C'$, we can add our extra vertex outside the existing boundary of $G$ and connect to all three boundary points, meaning that we now have $|E|+3=3v-6+3 = 3v-3$ edges as required.